# template for documenting technology stack

Tags: java, architecture, documentation

I have to document the technology stack for my platform on which products are built by other groups and organizations. Do you guys suggest any templates (standard or not) for this? I believe there are templates out there but googling did not help much

I am also trying to find an article that was posted on www.javalobby.com sometime ago that had all the categories I need and also the suggested libraries. For e.g for Category=caching, library=ehcache. If anyone of you are aware of than article, please provide the link.

**This is not a subjective question. I am just looking for various ways of documenting the stack.**

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Never used any template for this. But if you use maven you could use maven-dependency-plugin to generate a dependency tree, then do some text transformations and manual editing. groupId, artifactId and versions will be there for sure and will help finding out which products you depends on.